# Failed to setup tftpd-hpa

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, tftp

I have seen people discussing this problem, but no-one seems to know the answer.

When I try to start my tftpd-hpa, by the command:

```
/etc/init.d/tftpd-hpa start
```

I am getting this in return:

```
    [....] Starting tftpd-hpa (via systemctl): tftpd-hpa.serviceJob for tftpd-
hpa.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See 

"systemctl status tftpd-hpa.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

     failed!
```

My `/etc/default/tftpd-hpa`

```
# /etc/default/tftpd-hpa

TFTP_USERNAME="fly!"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/tftpboot"
TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure"
RUN_DAEMON="yes" # maybe no need for that
#OPTIONS="-l -s /var/lib/tftpboot"
```

Output of `systemctl status tftpd-hpa.service`

```
● tftpd-hpa.service - LSB: HPA's tftp server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tftpd-hpa; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Пн 2016-11-28 19:45:33 +05; 4min 38s
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 3217 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/tftpd-hpa start (code=exited, status=1/FAI

ноя 28 19:45:33 serverubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: HPA's tftp server...
ноя 28 19:45:33 serverubuntu tftpd-hpa[3217]:  * Starting HPA's tftpd in.tftpd
ноя 28 19:45:33 serverubuntu tftpd-hpa[3217]: /tftpboot missing, aborting.
ноя 28 19:45:33 serverubuntu systemd[1]: tftpd-hpa.service: Control process exit
ноя 28 19:45:33 serverubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: HPA's tftp server.
ноя 28 19:45:33 serverubuntu systemd[1]: tftpd-hpa.service: Unit entered failed 
ноя 28 19:45:33 serverubuntu systemd[1]: tftpd-hpa.service: Failed with result '
lines 1-13/13 (END)
```

Why does not it work? How to fix it?

OS - Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS

- I visited this [Launchpad bug report # 1342580](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tftp-hpa/+bug/1342580)

  and change `0:69` to `0.0.0.0:69`, also I change the line  '`start on`' condition in `/etc/init/tftpd-hpa.conf` to:

  ```
  start on (filesystem and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
  ```

  It does not work either.

Comment: where do you have tftp files stored?

Answer (score 2):

The path is wrong:

> ```
> ноя 28 19:45:33 serverubuntu tftpd-hpa[3217]: /tftpboot missing, aborting.
> ```

`tftpd-hpa` is looking for `/tftpboot` where I expect you are following the official PXE tutorial which set it in `/var/lib/tftpboot`

Quick fix, uncomment the line below in `/etc/default/tftpd-hpa`:

```
OPTIONS="-l -s /var/lib/tftpboot"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as following：

```
root@ubuntu:/# sudo service tftpd-hpa restart
Job for tftpd-hpa.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status tftpd-hpa.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

root@ubuntu:/etc/default# vi tftpd-hpa

# /etc/default/tftpd-hpa
TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="\tftpboot"
TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="-l -c -s"
```

After changing `TFTP_DIRECTORY="\tftpboot"` to `TFTP_DIRECTORY="/tftpboot"`, it works:

```
root@ubuntu:/# /etc/init.d/tftpd-hpa start
[ ok ] Starting tftpd-hpa (via systemctl): tftpd-hpa.service.
```

Comment: ... provided that `/tftpboot` exists, which it does not do for the user in the question.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, i am using a Debian 10.

Do the following commands:

```
sudo apt install tftpd-hpa
```

After installation, you need to edit the configuration file, open it in a text editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/tftpd-hpa
```

Then make the file to be like this:

```
TFTP_USERNAME="nobody"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/tftpboot/"
TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure --create -v"
```

Create a directory for files and assign rights:

```
sudo mkdir /srv/tftp
sudo chown tftp:tftp /srv/tftp
```

Restart the TFTP server to apply the changes:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tftpd-hpa restart
```

I got the instructions on https://ixnfo.com/en/install-and-configure-tftpd-hpa.html

Answer (score -1):

In my case,the service `tftpd` had gotten installed along with `tftp-hpa`.

The error that I was getting was:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tftpd-hpa restart

[....] Restarting tftpd-hpa (via systemctl): tftpd-hpa.serviceJob for tftpd-hpa.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status tftpd-hpa.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

And when I did status call:

```
sudo service tftpd-hpa status

● tftpd-hpa.service - LSB: HPA's tftp server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tftpd-hpa; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-06-04 19:39:04 IST; 8min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

Jun 04 19:39:04 sophos systemd[1]: Starting LSB: HPA's tftp server...
Jun 04 19:39:04 sophos tftpd-hpa[2526]:  * Starting HPA's tftpd in.tftpd
Jun 04 19:39:04 sophos systemd[1]: tftpd-hpa.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 04 19:39:04 sophos systemd[1]: tftpd-hpa.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 04 19:39:04 sophos systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: HPA's tftp server.
```

So I removed the tftpd:

```
sudo apt-get purge tftpd -y
```

Then did a service restart:

```
sudo service tftpd-hpa restart
```

And the service started running:

```
sudo service tftpd-hpa status

● tftpd-hpa.service - LSB: HPA's tftp server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tftpd-hpa; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2020-06-04 19:47:22 IST; 4s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 3152 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/tftpd-hpa start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 04 19:47:22 sophos systemd[1]: Starting LSB: HPA's tftp server...
Jun 04 19:47:22 sophos systemd[1]: Started LSB: HPA's tftp server.
```

Thank You.

Comment: Sorry for the indentation issue, this was my first contribution so I was not able to get the indentation properly.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post questions as answers to existing questions, create your own instead. You can still link to this question using the URL in the "share" link if you think this helps establish context.

Comment: Your answer seems unrelated to the user's question (apart from being about the same `tftp` server implementation). You answer does not answer the question as given.